# how to start opennms after building source code

Tags: java, opennms

I have downloaded **opennms-source-1.10.0-2.tar** and build the source code successfully according to http://opennms.org/wiki/Eclipse_and_OpenNMS.

Now i want to run/start opennnms and develop the code according to my business requirement.
Any idea how to start opennms?.

Comment: [Configuring OpenNMS](http://opennms.org/wiki/Docu-overview#Configuring_OpenNMS) does not help?

Comment: @Raghuram:thnx 4 ur reply.I looked into the link provided by you.But where can i find the steps to run the code from eclipse or jetty server.

Comment: i dont have any idea how to start. so i prefer step by step procedure as i am completely new to this opennms.

Comment: You cannot start the code from jetty or eclipse. OpenNMS must run by itself in DEBUG mode (`opennms -t start`). You can then remote debug to a running instance of OpenNMS.

Answer (score 0):

**OpenNMS Dev Setup on Windows ( Can take bulid and start server in windows )**

```
1.Download Opennms latest source code

2.Download latest Java JDK and install it. Set JAVA_HOME path

3.Download Postgres and install it. Set the path in environment variable

4.Download Perl and install it. Set path in environment variable 

5.Unzip the opennms source code and put it your local server
  (Ex : D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Source\opennms)

6.Set the mavan bin path in environment variable
  (Ex : D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Source\opennms\maven\bin)

7.Enter into D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Source\opennms> path

8.Clean your project 
  (Ex : D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Source\opennms>perl clean.pl)

9.Compile your opennms project
  (Ex : D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Source\opennms>perl compile.pl)

10.Assemple your or build your project
  (Ex : D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Source\opennms>perl assemple.pl -Dopennms.home=D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Build)

11.Copy your build file opennms-1.13.0-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz from D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Source\opennms\target folder

12.Put it your build opennms home location and unzip it
   (Ex : D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Build)

13.Now your folder structure in build path should be the folllowing hira
   Build
     - bin
     - etc
     - ...

14.Create install.bat file with the following content

SET OPENNMS_HOME=D:/Workspace/OpenNMS/Build
SET DBNAME=opennms
SET DBURL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/
SET ETCDIR=%OPENNMS_HOME%/etc
SET SERVLETDIR=%OPENNMS_HOME%/webapps/opennms

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\java" -Xmx512m "-Dopennms.home=%OPENNMS_HOME%" "-Dinstall.dir=%OPENNMS_HOME%" "-Dinstall.database.name=%DBNAME%" "-Dinstall.database.url=%DBURL%" "-Dinstall.etc.dir=%ETCDIR%" "-Dinstall.servlet.dir=%SERVLETDIR%" -classpath "%OPENNMS_HOME%/lib/opennms_bootstrap.jar;%OPENNMS_HOME%/lib/opennms_install.jar" org.opennms.install.Installer %*


15.Download jicmp.dll and jicmp6.dll file and put it in your java bin folder
  (Ex : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin)

16.Change your postgres password in D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Build\etc\opennms-datasources.xml file

    <jdbc-data-source name="opennms-admin"

                        database-name="template1"

                        class-name="org.postgresql.Driver"

                        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/template1"

                        user-name="postgres"

                        password="postgres" />

17.Create the opennms database for opennms source with help of install.bat file
  (Ex : D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Build\bin>install.bat -d)

18.Create opennms.bat file with the following content to start opennms bulid

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\java" -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dopennms.home="D:/Workspace/OpenNMS/Build" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$OPENNMS_HOME/lib/endorsed" -jar "D:/Workspace/OpenNMS/Build/lib/opennms_bootstrap.jar" %*

19.To run the opennms server, Open cmd prompt in admin mode and run opennms.bat file
  (Ex : D:\Workspace\OpenNMS\Build\bin>opennms.bat start)
```

Answer (score 0):

To develop

1. Download the opennms code and build it by giving "sudo mvn install -DskipTests" in opennms home directory.
   Note - ensure you have full access to the internet, otherwise compilation may fail.
2. Build will complete in less than 15mins when you have 8GB RAM machine.
3. now go to openms_home_directory/bin and issue "sudo opennms start" this will start your opennms.
4. Add java files or modules according to your business needs.
5. build the project again, in the respective maven project folder, you will have pom.xml and generated target folder. Go to target folder and the copy the jar and place it in the installed opennms directory /usr/share/opennms/lib and restart the server.